# The keyboard can not lift the edit text because the scrollview

Tags: java, android

When the keyboard is going up she exceeding the textView
Instead pick it up (pick up all the linearLayout )

You can see it in my code 
And as I said the keyboard covers the textView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cvsTvHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="368dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cvsLlVerticalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="274dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cvsEtPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.07"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cvsBtuSendPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

public class ConversationActivity extends Activity {

```
myApp app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
    app = (myApp)getApplication();

    setHeaderText();
    sendPost();
}

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}

private void setHeaderText() {

    TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cvsTvHeader);
    String text = app.bar.arrPostsObj.get(app.indexPostObjInArrPostObj).post;
    tv.setText(text);

}

private void sendPost() {

    Button btu =(Button)findViewById(R.id.cvsBtuSendPost);
    btu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addpost();

        }
    });

}

public void addpost() {

       EditText et = getPostText();
       if (et != null) {

           String text = et.getText().toString();
           int i = 0;
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {

            for ( i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

                char c = text.charAt(i);
                if (c != ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (i < text.length()) {
                final TextView tv = new TextView(this);

                tv.setText(text);
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

                tv.setId(app.arrPostLls.size());

                    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ll.addView(tv); //ll.addView(tv, index)
                    LinearLayout llL =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.cvsLlVerticalScrollView);
                    llL.addView(ll);
                    app.arrPostLls.add(ll);


            }

        }

        finishPost(0, null, et, false, false);

    }


}

private EditText getPostText() {

    EditText et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cvsEtPost);

    return et;

}

private void finishPost(int index,PostObject postObject,EditText et,boolean boolNewPost,boolean boolGFather) {

    et.setText("");
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0); 

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to have root view as scrollview in this case,

```
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cvsTvHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="368dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" >

                    <!-- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/cvsLlVerticalScrollView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="274dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cvsEtPost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.07"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cvsBtuSendPost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: It works partially
The inner scrollview not working.
I have a function that fills the inner scrollview.
he Generates textViwe and puts it to cvsLlVerticalScrollView.
When he is filled impossible to roll and see the new data.

Answer (score 0):

What i got from your question is that you are not able to provide input in textViews placed at the lower end of the activity page. For that simpley apply a Scrollview to the whole layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context=".MyActivity"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cvsTvHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="368dp">
            <!--  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cvsLlVerticalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="274dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cvsEtPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.07"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cvsBtuSendPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry it does not work I get
Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log